# Get Count based on condition from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table , the columns that I am focused on are `Id` which is unique identifier,  `Value` which is a decimal vote

I know how to group by `Id` and get a count of all rows having a `Value` of greater than 3.  ( We're counting a `Value` > 3 as a `Vote` and a `Value` less than 2.9 to be -1 `Vote`)  - moving from starts to thumbs up/down. anyways that doesn't matter .  It was just to explain or rating system.

My question is :  How can I do a query that

```
  select Id, Value,  count(*) as [COUNT]  
  from [Ratings]
  group by Id, Value 
  having Value > 3.0
  order by Id desc
```

I do the opposite to get down votes,  how do I make in one single query to return all Id's and the number of votes ( if Value > 3 that would be 1 `Vote` if `Value` is less than 3 that would be -1 `Vote`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select Id,
       (sum(case when Value > 3.0 then 1 else 0 end) -
        sum(case when Value < 3.0 then 1 else 0 end) -- or maybe 2.9
       ) as TotalVotes
from [Ratings]
group by Id 
order by Id desc;
```

Alternatively, you could write:

```
select id, sum(case when Value > 3.0 then 1 else -1 end)
```

Comment: actually , there is something wrong with the first version ,  it's getting an error "Expecting , AND or OR" at the ")" after both sum()   , the second one works great though

Comment: @ScottSelby . . . I must have misread the tags.  That was MySQL syntax, not SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server allows you to specify condition in aggregate functions.In your case, you need to use SUM with conditions..

So, this is how your final query looks like

```
  select Id, Value,SUM(CASE WHEN Value>3.0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS VoteCount 
  from [Ratings]
  group by Id 
  order by Id desc
```